# Access Google API using python: Refresh Error 'invalid grant' appears suddenly after a few days of first-time setup

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Within last 10days, with python 3 and by using the `google_auth_oauthlib` and `googleapiclient` packages, I have been able to create Google Sheet (using python code) and do basic write/read values to any cell. I accomplished this by going through random videos on Youtube.

Suddenly today evening, the code stopped working with the following error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

I am new to Google API and have no clue why this is happening. Is there something I need to 'reset' in my account in console.cloud.google.com to avoid this?

Following is the code which used to work fine before, but doesnt now:

```
import os
from Google import Create_Service

spreadsheet_id= '1F8mAvHWqHL_3JHuKnv9Fy9vm2_Zm2tR13DNKj9oNxzU'

FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\Users\Owner'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, 'Client_Secret2.json')
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
service.spreadsheets().values().clear(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    range='A1:AA1000',
    body={}
).execute()
```

Here is code for `Google.py`which has `Create_Service` :

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Here is the photo from my `console.cloud.google.com` :

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example].  Is your app still in testing phase.

Comment: @DalmTo I have added my code and Google API dashboard snapshot. Can you please elaborate what does 'testing phase' means. I started with Google API for the first time this week and simply followed a youtube video to get setup. This is a personal project I took up to learn in my spare time, so I guess I will always like to be in "Testing" phase... Please shed light how this works.

Comment: Testing means that you are still working on it and its not done yet.

Comment: can you add your code for Create_Service

Comment: Just now, I added the code for `Google.py` which  has the code for `Create_Service`

Answer (score 2):

To be clear. This has nothing to do with your credentials file.  Your credentials file is unaffected by this error.

> 'Token has been expired or revoked.'

Means that your app not longer has access to the users account.  Either the access token you are using has expired and you have not requested off line access so do not have a refresh token.   Or the refresh token has been revoked.

Cauess for refresh token revoked.

- the user has revoked your access via their google account.
- the user has authorized your app more then 50 times and you are not storing the most recent refresh token
- Your app is still set to testing in google developer console and there for it will expire after seven days.

Solution to all of the above is to request access of the user again.   If you are following the [People quickstart python](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python).  Delete 'token.json' it will cause your app to request access again.

## Refresh token [expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

[image]

Comment: @DalmTo please see my comments above, i added my code and Google API. I am unsure what "Testing" phase means. Do I need to change being from Testing phase if I intend to use this code for my personal amateur learning project?

Comment: Then you will need to accept your refresh token will expire.

Comment: By refresh token, do you mean I would have to manually visit https://console.cloud.google.com/ and regenerate a new `.json` file and then replace the existing one with it? What is the procedure to refresh the token?  Alternatively, what is a long term solution and what does it mean to assign myself to not be in 'Testing' mode anymore?

Comment: You said your new at this right.   Why dont you go watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w .   When your done you should understand what your issue is.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link, it certainly helped get some idea about what my code is about. My code is something I got online and I simply started using it after setting up account in console.cloud.google.com. From the video it seems my issue is not due to the 'requestToken' or 'AuthorizationCode' but rather due to 'refresh token' discussed in video minute7 onwards. However, I am still at a loss to understand what exact step (or changes to my above code) I need to take to overcome the issue and regenerate the token. Can you please shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by deleting the `.pickle` file I had in my python folder. Re-running my code self-generated a new `.pickle` file and the code runs now!

Comment: My answer did mention that you would need to delete the  'token.json'  or .pickle when the refresh token expired.  Im not sure why you would need to post another answer.  You could have just posted this as a comment on my answer.   Remember to accept an answer when it helps you it improves your rep.

Comment: Is 'token.json' and 'pickle' the same thing? My python folder has both .json file and .pickle file. Deleting .pickle is what helped, i did not touch .json at all. Sorry if I am misunderstanding but you mentioned 'Delete 'token.json' but didnt say anythin about the .pickle.